# How to query tables that have conflicting name?

Tags: sql

i have a table called ORDER, when i try to query it using

```
select * from Order
```

i get the error 'invalid query'
how to do access this table please?
thank you

Comment: In SQL Server, I would try "SELECT * FROM [Order]"

Comment: Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it.

Comment: In this particular case, the solution is specific to the database engine you're using.  It would be `[ORDER]` in SQL Server and Access (and SQLite), `'ORDER'` in some other variants, and `\`ORDER\`` in still other variants.

Comment: @DavidFaber While that could answer the question, since they've failed to mention their database I wouldn't suggest a SQL Server solution as a duplicate.

Comment: Closed as duplicate for a SQL-Server specific question. Not sure I agree with this one. Seems a bit contradictory to the comments by @bluefeet!

Answer (score 5):

## Step 1

Don't ever used reserved words for object (or column) names.

- [SQL 1992 Standard](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/%7Eshadow/sql/sql1992.txt) (search for `<reserved word>`)
- [SQL Server reserved words](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx)
- [MySQL reserved words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html)
- [DB2 reserved words](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_reservedwords.dita)

## Step 2

If you've inherited such a thing that you are not able to change, then you need to use "quoted identifiers".

I advocate

```
SELECT *
FROM   "Order"
```

As it is a standard identifier, so will work better across platforms.

Comment: Downvoted because? It would be nice to hear reasoning so answers can be adjusted.

Comment: I am guessing that someone thinks that double quotes are database-specific.  You should probable edit to specify that they're standard in "recent" versions of SQL.

Comment: Recent? It's been there for ages, since SQL-1 or SQL-2?

Comment: Yep, double quotes have been the standard for a long time.
Source: SQL 1992 documentation - http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt

Answer (score 2):

ORDER is a reserved word in SQL. Put double quotes around it:

```
select * from "Order"
```

And also, I personally think ORDERS is a better name. (Because several orders are stored in the table.)

Late edit: List of reserved words, in different versions of the SQL standard:
http://developer.mimer.com/standard/reservedwords/sql-reserved-words.tml

Comment: P.S. massive +1 for your recommended table name. It's very rare a table name shouldn't be a plural... how often does it only contain a single row!

Answer (score -1):

It's generally a good idea to not use reserved words for database object names (tables, views & etc.). Sometimes you just got to deal with it though. The below query should work for you.

```
select * from [Order]
```

Just put the brackets around the table name.

Hope this helps!

Comment: What platform is OP using?

Comment: I see where you are coming from. However, I can't post comments on questions since my rating is low since I'm a new member to the board.

Comment: Until you have the necessary reputation, I would recommend that you wait for the OP to edit their question to contain everything you need to give a good answer. Otherwise, I would go to another question.